# Set data dynamically based on environment in a TCA file

Tags: typo3

We're using the [external_import](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/external_import/) extension on a client project to import data into their database.

Part of this config exists in the TCA file for the table in question and looks something like this:

```
    'external' => [
        0 => [
            'connector' => 'csv',
            'parameters' => [
                'filename' => $extensionPath . 'fileadmin/csv_import.csv',
                'delimiter' => ",",
                'text_qualifier' => '"',
                'skip_rows' => 1,
                'encoding' => 'latin1'
            ],
            'data' => 'array',
            'referenceUid' => 'reference_uid', # unique reference contained within the external file, this is required
            'priority' => 10,
            'disabledOperations' => 'delete',
            'description' => 'Import of GEMS data for funding awarded',
            'pid' => 61, # where to import the records to, this will probably need to be stored dynamically somewhere
        ]
    ]
```

Most of this is irrelevant to the question, but I figured I'd add it for context - the issue is that last value, `pid`, needs to be set to a different value based on the environment.

We can't hard code it, because the value is going to be different on different environments, so wanted to know if there's some way we can define the value within the typo3 back end, and have to populate the TCA accordingly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i assume that you need backend manageable setting which reflect to the TCA file. I got way to accomplish 
your requirement with Global extension setting.

Create new constant for your extension (ext_conf_template.txt). you can manage setting from the EM (https://prnt.sc/i17sli)
Code:

```
# cat=basic/int; type=int; label=Parent page uid (PID) for records of myTable
myTablePID = 0
```

In your TCA file you can extract your custom extension configuration like this,

```
$confArr = unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['myext']);
// You will get all the configuration settings here. you can access particular value with index $confArr['myTablePID']
// print_r($confArr);die();
```

Add this code top of the TCA file. Have a look at the code i have changed.

```
    'external' => [
        0 => [
            'connector' => 'csv',
            'parameters' => [
                'filename' => $extensionPath . 'fileadmin/csv_import.csv',
                'delimiter' => ",",
                'text_qualifier' => '"',
                'skip_rows' => 1,
                'encoding' => 'latin1'
            ],
            'data' => 'array',
            'referenceUid' => 'reference_uid', # unique reference contained within the external file, this is required
            'priority' => 10,
            'disabledOperations' => 'delete',
            'description' => 'Import of GEMS data for funding awarded',
            'pid' => $confArr['myTablePID'], # where to import the records to, this will probably need to be stored dynamically somewhere
        ]
    ]
```

Hope this will help you! Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ext_conf_template.txt` file in your extension to make configuration possibilities, once you installed the extension.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html

In that way, you can change the configuration on a per-installation (environment) basis and get the data like this

```
$backendConfiguration =
(bool)\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ExtensionConfiguration::class)
->get('your_extension_key', 'temporaryDirectory');
```

Code taken from the docs-link above